# Issue contacting couchbase servers from iis with couchbase dotnet SDK 3.1

Tags: .net, iis, couchbase

We have an existing large IIS application (.NET Framework 4.6.2), which uses old couchbase SDK and worked great with couchbase server (Community Edition 6.6.0 build 7909 ).
Now we want to upgrade to the latest couchbase dotnet SDK 3.1,
after replacing the relevant code and testing it locally contacting local couchbase server, I have tested it on a QA server configured to contact a couchbase server cluster (4 nodes) on the same environment.

But the app could not reach to the couchbase server, and throws an exception on the initialization of bucket/cluster :

```
var options = new ClusterOptions
{
   UserName = userName,
   Password = password,
   Buckets = new List<string> { bucketName },
   ConnectionString = connectionString,
   Logging = loggerFactory 
};
var cluster = Cluster.ConnectAsync(options).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var bucket = cluster.BucketAsync(bucketName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Very generic exception - "Bucket with name <<MY_BUCKET_NAME>> not exists". (The bucket exists and user credentials are correct.)

Despite the fact that when I ping (from qa server)the same (couchbase's) hostname in our internal network - I get replies.
And the results from [sdk-doctor](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/sdk-doctor)  diagnose  (with the same hostname, bucket and credentials) is successful.

we have tried with a simple console application (same .net framework version) to run on that same server simple initialization (same hostname, bucket and credentials) and lookup from the same couchbase server and it worked fine.

We have also tried to add the mapping of the nodes to hosts file.

do know any reason for this behavior ? or idea for a solution.
thanks.

We have also added loggerFactory to ClusterOptions to get the internal logs of couchbase :

```
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Trace] The subject is bootstrapped: True 
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Debug] Setting TCP Keep-Alives using Socket.IOControl on <<MY_COUCHBASE_SERVER'S_IP>>:11210 - enable tcp keep-alives True, time 00:01:00, interval 00:00:01 
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Debug] Starting connection initialization on server <<MY_COUCHBASE_SERVER'S_IP>>:11210. 
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Debug] Executing op Helo on <<MY_COUCHBASE_SERVER'S_IP>>:11210 with key {"i":"598d37c53bdeca6b/0000000000000003","a":"couchbase-net-sdk/3.1.0.0 (clr/.NET Framework 4.7.3740.0) (os/Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763 )"} and opaque 8. 
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Debug] Completed executing op <<MY_COUCHBASE_SERVER'S_IP>>:11210 on Helo with key {"i":"598d37c53bdeca6b/0000000000000003","a":"couchbase-net-sdk/3.1.0.0 (clr/.NET Framework 4.7.3740.0) (os/Microsoft Windows 10.0.17763 )"} and opaque 8 
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Debug] Executing op GetErrorMap on <<MY_COUCHBASE_SERVER'S_IP>>:11210 with key  and opaque 10. 
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Debug] Completed executing op <<MY_COUCHBASE_SERVER'S_IP>>:11210 on GetErrorMap with key  and opaque 10 
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Information] v=aHXI6YkwbZvurZIipatRL2KcKb8= 
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Debug] Connection for <<MY_COUCHBASE_SERVER'S_IP>>:11210 has been started. 
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Information] Cannot bootstrap bucket qa as Couchbase.    at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger`1.Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.Log[TState](LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func`3 formatter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.Log(ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, Exception exception, String message, Object[] args)
   at Couchbase.Core.IO.Connections.ConnectionFactory.<CreateAndConnectAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Couchbase.Core.IO.Connections.ConnectionPoolBase.<CreateConnectionAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Couchbase.Core.IO.Connections.DataFlow.DataFlowConnectionPool.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<<AddConnectionsAsync>g__StartConnection|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Couchbase.Core.IO.Connections.DataFlow.DataFlowConnectionPool.<AddConnectionsAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Couchbase.Core.IO.Connections.DataFlow.DataFlowConnectionPool.<InitializeAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Couchbase.Core.ClusterNode.<InitializeAsync>d__107.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Couchbase.Core.DI.ClusterNodeFactory.<CreateAndConnectAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Couchbase.Core.ClusterContext.<CreateAndBootStrapBucketAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Couchbase.Core.ClusterContext.<GetOrCreateBucketAsync>d__51.MoveNext()
[2021-02-07 09:10:03+00:00] [Debug] Cannot set ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback, not supported on this platform
```

after that there's the same sequence but with "Cannot bootstrap bucket <<MY_BUCKET_NAME>> as Memcached." and another with "Cannot bootstrap bucket <<MY_BUCKET_NAME>> as Ephemeral."